# On Final Fantasy IV for Steam, how can I get all the augments in the minimum amount of playthroughs?

Tags: steam, final-fantasy-4

I'm playing Final Fantasy IV (for the bazillionth time) and want to try using all the augments but found out I need to play through multiple times.

How many times must I play through the game to get all the augments with minimum playthrough? Which augments should I give to which characters to make this happen? I'm willing to try a save editor (steam version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 1 playthrough and at least portions of a 2nd playthrough in order to obtain all of the augments. [Here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/android/695717-final-fantasy-iv/faqs/51274?single=1#section352) is a link to a FAQ on GameFAQs that details a suggested augment path. You can use this to determine how far through the New Game+ you need to get in order to obtain all of the augments. Throughout the walkthrough that also appears on the page, it details the requirements for obtaining a particular augment. Hope this helps.